# D3 "tokens" representing different values, tally visual

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The visual I have in mind is basically a tally visual (a marker/icon for each observation), but given the spread of my data it will be preferable to have some markers/icons to be worth more than others. For instance look at this data, specifically `t1fc` and `t2fc`:

```
var data = [
  {'continent':'Asia', 't1fg':19, 't2fg':24, 't1fc':758, 't2fc':773},
  {'continent':'Europe', 't1fg':6, 't2fg':37, 't1fc':234, 't2fc':241},
  {'continent':'North America', 't1fg':20, 't2fg':60, 't1fc':102, 't2fc':102},
  {'continent':'South America', 't1fg':-2, 't2fg':22, 't1fc':1, 't2fc':1},
  {'continent':'Other', 't1fg':3, 't2fg':4, 't1fc':5, 't2fc':5},
];
```

On the lower end we are in the single digits, but on the higher end we are well into the 700's. In light of this I would like to create different markers: a big rect for representing 100s, a medium rect representing 10s, and a small rect representing 1s.

For instance let's take `data[0].t1fc` which is `758`. To visualize this number with the tally system I have in mind I'd have to append 7 big rects, 5 medium rects and 8 small rects -- and I'd need to keep them within a vertical range of 150 pixels (so we'd have to sprawl things out horizontally).

This is what I have cooked up (the following are the heights/widths I had in mind for the squares):

```
var bigRect = 70;
var medRect = 30;
var smallRect = 15;
```

I thought I could try to append the rects using arrays of bools like this:

```
var blockData = [];

data.forEach(function(item) {
  blockData.push(item.t1fc/100)
})

var bigBlocks = [];

for (var i=0; i<blockData.length; i++) {
  var temp = [];
  for (var j=0; j<blockData[i]; j++) {
    if (blockData[i]>1) {
      temp.push(true)
    }
  }

  bigBlocks.push(temp);
}
```

Here the problem is now I can't append the rects with the rest of my data, because I'm essentially creating another data set. Ideally, I'd like to implement my tally rect system within the following group framework:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', 700)
        .attr('height', 150)
        .style("display", "block")
```

### Question

Is there anyway to implement my categorical tally rect visual within an existing group framework? Perhaps it's best to separate them and just align the rects so they have the same `x` and `y` logic as my original group. For scalability's sake, I'd still like to know if there is one unified way.

**Note:** Feel free to scrap my array of bools idea if you know of a more concise/better way.

Comment: Is [this](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/1fcabb17a80c41244da3888851e9f1b7) the type of structure you are looking for - blocks representing numbers spread across multiple elements?